# How to get PID of the subprocess with subprocess check_output

Tags: python, subprocess, pid

In my python script I'm trying to run some long lasting download process, like in the example below, and need to find a PID of the process started by check_output:

```
out = subprocess.check_output(["rsync","-azh","file.log",...])
```

Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run your subprocess using `Popen` instead:

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen(["rsync","-azh","file.log",...], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out = proc.communicate()[0]
pid = proc.pid
```

Generally, `Popen` object gives you better control and more info of the subprocess, but requires a bit more to setup. (Not much, though.) You can read more in the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html).

Comment: What is the use of `out = proc.communicate()[0]` line?

Comment: Use of `out = proc.communicate()[0]` line can be avoided. The original author hasn't accepted the edit for a long time.

Comment: Which edit? The `out = proc.communicate()[0]` is there to capture the output (`stdout`) of the process in the same way as is is done in the original question.

Comment: If someone tries to suggest an edit - it shows up "edit queue is full". I initially wanted to submit an edit but after your answer, I think it is ok to not submit a new one. But there might be edits from other people.